# Sort values with multi-index/ groupby object 'by group' without breaking the index level

Tags: pandas

Is it possible to sort values by the count values of each group's sum. without breaking the index level? Both attempts I commented out would sort but breaks the index level.

```
#DataFrame
ff = pd.DataFrame([('P1', 17, 'male'),
                   ('P2', 10, 'female'),
                   ('P3', 10, 'male'),
                   ('P4', 19, 'female'),
                   ('P5', 10, 'male'),
                   ('P6', 12, 'male'),
                   ('P7', 12, 'male'),
                   ('P8', 15, 'female'),
                   ('P9', 15, 'female'),
                   ('P10', 10, 'male')],
                  columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Sex'])

# Attempts
(
    ff
    .groupby(['Age', 'Sex'])
    .agg(**{
        'Count': pd.NamedAgg(column="Name", aggfunc='count'),
        'Who': pd.NamedAgg(column="Name", aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join([i for i in x]))})
#     .sort_values('Count')           <- this breaks the index level
#     .sort_values(['Count', 'Age'])  <- this too breaks the index level
)
```

**Original Data:**

|  |  | Count | Who |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | Sex |  |  |
| 10 | Female | 1 | p2 |
|  | male | 3 | p3,p5,p10 |
| 12 | male | 2 | p6,p7 |
| 15 | female | 2 | p8,p9 |
| 17 | male | 1 | p1 |
| 19 | female | 1 | p4 |

**Desired Output: (sort values by the sum of 'Age' group, but keep the grouped index)**

|  |  | Count | Who |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | Sex |  |  |
| 17 | male | 1 | p1 |
| 19 | female | 1 | p4 |
| 12 | male | 2 | p6,p7 |
| 15 | female | 2 | p8,p9 |
| 10 | Female | 1 | p2 |
|  | male | 3 | p3,p5,p10 |

---

Edit: This is how I finally solve the problem, any more advices are appreciated.

```
# DataFrame -- I update a bit for testcases.
ff = pd.DataFrame([('P1', 19, 'male'),
                   ('P2', 10, 'female'),
                   ('P3', 10, 'male'),
                   ('P4', 19, 'female'),
                   ('P5', 10, 'male'),
                   ('P6', 12, 'male'),
                   ('P7', 12, 'male'),
                   ('P7', 12, 'male'),
                   ('P7', 12, 'male'),
                   ('P7', 12, 'male'),
                   ('P8', 15, 'female'),
                   ('P9', 15, 'female'),
                   ('P10', 10, 'male')],
                  columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Sex'])

# It works !
(
    ff.groupby(['Age', 'Sex']).agg(**{
    'Count': pd.NamedAgg(column="Name", aggfunc='count'),
    'Who': pd.NamedAgg(column="Name", aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join([i for i in x]))})
    # Sort by 'Count' and keep the group adding 'tmp'
    .assign(
        tmp=lambda x: x.reset_index().groupby('Age')['Count'].transform('sum').to_numpy())
    .sort_values(['tmp','Age'])
     # drop tmp
    .drop('tmp', axis=1)
)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to sort by?

Comment: what do you mean by *without breaking the index level*?

Comment: Hi, the commented lines indicates what's going on, basically it means it'll sort by 'count' and break, for example, age 10's group into 2 unsuccessive  rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and sorting index by sum of both `Sex` values if exist, then reshape back by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.unstack()
df1 = df1.sort_index(key=df1.sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True).get).stack().astype(df.dtypes)
print (df1)
            Count          Who
Age Sex                       
17  male        1           P1
19  female      1           P4
12  male        2       P6, P7
15  female      2       P8, P9
10  female      1           P2
    male        3  P3, P5, P10
```

Another idea is sorting by sum both values with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['tmp'] = df.groupby('Age')['Count'].transform('sum')

df1 = df.sort_values(['tmp','Age']).drop('tmp', axis=1)
print (df1)
             Count          Who
Age Sex                       
17  male        1           P1
19  female      1           P4
12  male        2       P6, P7
15  female      2       P8, P9
10  female      1           P2
    male        3  P3, P5, P10
```

EDIT: One line solution is:

```
df = (
    ff
    .groupby(['Age', 'Sex'])
    .agg(**{
        'Count': pd.NamedAgg(column="Name", aggfunc='count'),
        'Who': pd.NamedAgg(column="Name", aggfunc=', '.join)})
    
    .assign(tmp = lambda x: x.groupby('Age')['Count'].transform('sum'))
    .sort_values(['tmp','Age'])
    .drop('tmp', axis=1))
print (df)
            Count          Who
Age Sex                       
17  male        1           P1
19  female      1           P4
12  male        2       P6, P7
15  female      2       P8, P9
10  female      1           P2
    male        3  P3, P5, P10
```

Comment: The second one works, and if I have to make it into one-liner ( for better readability using .function each line), I've updated the question to show how I did this. Is there any redundant code or anything that could be improved?

Comment: @Cookie - answer was edited.

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I was doing, great to know! Is it common to make tmp column and drop them?

Comment: @Cookie - no, but here is sorting by 2 columns, so used this solution.

Answer (score 2):

There you go.

Let's keep the temp variable in `data`.

```py
data = ff.groupby(['Age', 'Sex']).agg(**{
    'Count': pd.NamedAgg(column="Name", aggfunc='count'),
    'Who': pd.NamedAgg(column="Name", aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join([i for i in x]))})
```

You can write a custom function to do what you want to do in each group by `apply` function.

For example.

```py
data.groupby("Age", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values("Count", ascending=False))
```

```
            Count          Who
Age Sex                       
10  male        3  P3, P5, P10
    female      1           P2
12  male        2       P6, P7
15  female      2       P8, P9
17  male        1           P1
19  female      1           P4
```

Or, change to `ascending order`

```py
data.groupby("Age", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values("Count", ascending=False))
```

```
            Count          Who
Age Sex                       
10  female      1           P2
    male        3  P3, P5, P10
12  male        2       P6, P7
15  female      2       P8, P9
17  male        1           P1
19  female      1           P4
```

Or if you wanna sort by each level of multi-index. you can do such way.

You can sort the index by adding `level` args in the `sort_index` function.

For example:

1. `data.sort_index(level=0, ascending=True)`

Sort the first index by ascending order.

```
            Count          Who
Age Sex                       
19  female      1           P4
17  male        1           P1
15  female      2       P8, P9
12  male        2       P6, P7
10  male        3  P3, P5, P10
    female      1           P2
```

2. `data.sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[False, True])`

Sort the first index in ascending order and the second index in descending order.

```
            Count          Who
Age Sex                       
19  female      1           P4
17  male        1           P1
15  female      2       P8, P9
12  male        2       P6, P7
10  female      1           P2
    male        3  P3, P5, P10
```

---

By the way.

The `breaking index level` is not a special result. It is just a **display optimizations**

For example.

You can create one by yourself like:

```py
pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[10,10,20,10,10],['F','M','F','M','F']],names=['A','B']))
```

```
      a
A  B   
10 F  1
   M  2
20 F  3
10 M  4
   F  5
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this only sorts index by 'Age' instead of its 'Count' Value. I've tried to duplicate some columns (in my case, I've copy past P7 so make it has the biggest count value, but all the sortings above would return sorted df by age.